# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for Outer Measure

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

**Question:**
Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on a set $\Omega$ and $E$ be a $\mu^*$-measurable set. Show that
$$
\mu^*(A) + \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cup E)
$$
for all $A \subseteq \Omega$.

**Attempt:**
The fact that $A\subseteq\Omega$ is not necessarily $\mu^*$-measurable means I cannot use countable additivity property.

By Carathéodory criterion and countable sub-additivity,
\begin{align}
\mu^*(A) + \mu^*(E) 
&= \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c) + \mu^*(E) \\
&\ge \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cup E)
\end{align}

How do I show the reverse inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your first equality with the following: $\mu^{*}(A\cup E)=\mu^{*}((A\cup E) \cap E) +\mu^{*}((A\cup E) \cap E^{c})=\mu^{*}(E) +\mu^{*}(A\cap E^{c})$

Comment: That was helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By Carathéodory criterion you also know that, because $E \subset \Omega$ is $\mu^*$-measurable then for any $A \subset \Omega$

$$\mu^*(A \cup E) = \mu^*(A \cap E^c) + \mu^*(E)$$

because

\begin{align*}
\left( A \cup E \right) \cap E^c &= A \cap E^c \\
\left(A \cup E \right) \cap E &= E
\end{align*}

So where you have your inequality could be an equality.

Comment: Oh that's smart! Thank you!